# how to locate button using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried many ways and seen many posts on Stackoverflow but i cannot find a solution.
I need to access this button and click it, any ideas?

```
<a class="button secondary radius" href="/logout"><i class="icon-2x icon-signout"> Logout</i></a>
```

Comment: If that is the only `<a>` element with `class="button secondary radius"`, then you could search by class.

Comment: _I have already tried this_ Show us what you tried.

Comment: What website is this from?

Comment: It worked thanks, i was searching by class name with parameters of "button secondary radius", turns out i only needed to search by one of them instead of all three so "button" alone worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this button has three classes `button` `secondary` and `radius`. Just use `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("name of the class")`.  Insert one of the classes from above but be carefull, the class can only be used onces on the entire page or you might run into issues.

Answer (score 3):

If there are other buttons with the same class names you can try this way

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@href="/logout"]').click();
```